# Extracting only interesting columns from ASCII table

Tags: python, tabular

I'm by no means a programmer but I stumbled over a really nasty fixed width ASCII table which might require me to become one :) (with some help from you guys I hope)

I did already ask Mr. Google for some advice and he pointed my in the direction of Python. So here I am - pretty lost :(

The offending table looks like this:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 ... columnN
   data    crap    crap    data    crap    crap   data
   data    crap    crap    data    crap    crap   data
   data    crap    crap    data    crap    crap   
   data            crap            crap    crap   
   data    crap    crap    data    crap    crap   data
   data    crap    crap    data    crap    crap   data
   data    crap    crap            crap    crap   data
   data    crap    crap    data    crap           data
   data    crap    crap    data    crap    crap   data
   data    crap    crap    data    crap    crap   data
```

As you can see the number of columns can vary and there are portions in the table which have no data and there are also columns which have data I"m not interested in.

My goal is to have a table at the end which looks like this:

```
column1 column4 column7 ... columnN
   data   data    data
   data   data    data
   data   data       
   data           
   data   data    data
   data   data    data
   data           data
   data   data    data
   data   data    data
   data   data    data
```

So, now all the columns I don't want are gone. That's basically my goal - a table which has only the columns I'm interested in. Do you think something like that can be done in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to read table information from a text file, and then re-format it.  Some basic processing might look like:

```
# First read content into an array
# Each item in the array will be a line of the file
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# Next, parse each line
data = []
for line in content:
    # You might need to split by spaces
    # This takes care of multiple whitespaces, so "data1   data2 data3    data4"
    # Becomes ['data1','data2','data3','data4']
    row = line.split()
    # Or, maybe you will need to split the row up by tabs into an array
    # [] is a list comprehension, strip() will remove extra whitespace
    row = [item.strip() for item in line.split('\t')]
    # Finally, append the row to your data array
    data.append(row)

# Now, print the data back to a file how you'd like
fout = open('output.txt','w')
for row in data:
   # For specific columns
   fout.write('{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(row[0],row[1],row[7],row[8]))
   # Or, if you just need to remove a couple columns, you might do:
   row.pop(6)
   row.pop(5)
   row.pop(4)
   fout.write(' '.join(row))
```

Comment: Hi Adam! I was playing with your solution and I think its a starting point for me to get my teethes into Python. Many thanks!

Comment: This'll remove columns that are empty from the list; `"data __________ crap __________ crap crap"` becomes `['data','crap','crap','crap']` with no empty columns in-between (underscores used to illustrate whitespace in comments).

Comment: Sure - and yes, if you don't want to remove random empty columns with split(), use Martijn Pieters' cool solution for preserving these based on a fixed character width of each column.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, this can be done. In python strings are sequences so you can slice up your rows into columns using fixed indices:

```
>>> row = "   data    crap    crap            crap    crap   data"
>>> width = 8 # Column width
>>> columns = [row[i*width:(i+1)*width].strip() for i in range((len(row)/width)+1)]
>>> columns
['data', 'crap', 'crap', '', 'crap', 'crap', 'data']
```

Now all you have to do is pick your columns:

```
>>> columns[0], columns[3], columns[6]
('data', '', 'data')
```

I can imagine that the above code looks like gibberish to you still though; I strongly recommend you start reading up on learning to program. Python is an excellent language to begin with, start with http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide and work your way up from there!

Comment: Many thanks Martijn! I'll try that as well. Right now my head is spinning from all this new Python stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

While I really think you should code this up in python for the sake of learning python, if all you want is to get it done, try using Excel!

- read in the table (I'd be surprised if Excel can't figure this out!)
- delete the columns you're not interested in
- export / saveas fixed width

Comment: Excel's "Text to Columns" feature (under the Data tab in Excel 2007) will handle this nicely. You can do it in Python as a learning experience, but it you just need to *get it done*, use Excel.

Comment: Thanks Daren, but the file is a little bit to big for Excel. Maybe I should have mentioned that - its a huge file. Btw your profile photo looks scary :)